# Is it possible to find who has built an exe file?

Tags: delphi, portable-executable

Having an exe file at hand, is it possible to find any information about the person who has compiled it? More specifically, does delphi compiler include its own licence information or OS user or even some hardware IDs in the executable?

Comment: Answer to question is no

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know the only information that delphi compiler includes in compiled executables are compiler version, SKU edition (Comunity edition, Proffessional, Enterprise, Architect) and whether it is registred or not.
As far as I know it does not include specific licence information like licence owner.

So if as a developper you want such information included in your executable you either need to fill up Version Info fields apropriately or use some tool for digitally signing your executable in which case the information from digital certificate like certificate owner will be included.

Comment: Is there any documentation on the information you say it is storing (SKU etc.)? Where and in which format does it store it?

Comment: @dummzeuch I would expect that this is not officially documented, at least the implementation and format details, since the primary purpose, one would assume, would be for Emba to retain the ability to inspect suspect published commercial software for licence compliance.

Comment: There is no official documentation for retrieving of this information available. Maybe just for compiler version. The reason for this is that if people would generally know of where such information is stored in executable they could then modify executable in a way to hide the fact that they might for instance be using pirated copy of Delphi for compiling of those executables.